# Optimizing python one-liner

Tags: python

I profiled my program, and more than 80% of the time is spent in this one-line function! How can I optimize it? I am running with PyPy, so I'd rather not use NumPy, but since my program is spending almost all of its time there, I think giving up PyPy for NumPy might be worth it. However, I would prefer to use the CFFI, since that's more compatible with PyPy.

```
#x, y, are lists of 1s and 0s. c_out is a positive int. bit is 1 or 0.
def findCarryIn(x, y, c_out, bit):

    return (2 * c_out +
            bit -
            sum(map(lambda x_bit, y_bit: x_bit & y_bit, x, reversed(y)))) #note this is basically a dot product.
```

Comment: Suggestion: try to post your problem on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Could you store (or temporarily put) your lists of 0's and 1's into an int (which can have any number of bits in them)? That way you might be able to process large numbers (or all) of them at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using Numpy, After testing with `timeit` , The fastest method for the summing (that you are doing) seems to be using simple for loop and summing over the elements,  Example -

```
def findCarryIn(x, y, c_out, bit):
    s = 0
    for i,j in zip(x, reversed(y)):
        s += i & j
    return (2 * c_out + bit - s)
```

Though this did not increase the performance by a lot (maybe 20% or so).

The results of timing tests (With different methods , `func4` containing the method described above) -

```
def func1(x,y):
    return sum(map(lambda x_bit, y_bit: x_bit & y_bit, x, reversed(y)))

def func2(x,y):
    return sum([i & j for i,j in zip(x,reversed(y))])

def func3(x,y):
    return sum(x[i] & y[-1-i] for i in range(min(len(x),len(y))))

def func4(x,y):
    s = 0
    for i,j in zip(x, reversed(y)):
        s += i & j
    return s

In [125]: %timeit func1(x,y)
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.02 µs per loop

In [126]: %timeit func2(x,y)
The slowest run took 6.42 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.9 µs per loop

In [127]: %timeit func3(x,y)
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.31 µs per loop

In [128]: %timeit func4(x,y)
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.2 µs per loop
```

Comment: what about replacing global name lookups with local vars? does it also make sense in PyPy?

Comment: You won't believe this: `func4` was so much better for PyPy's JIT that it went from 82 sec to 12.5 sec!!! I'm going to let the PyPy devs know, it's ridiculous that simply exposing the loop lets the JIT optimize it so much more.

Comment: @Kos you mean builtin lookups? I do not see global name lookups.

Comment: @AnandSKumar I mean replacing `LOAD_GLOBAL` with `LOAD_FAST`

Comment: the simple loop does not need to allocate the list, which is why pypy can make it so much faster. It's very hard to avoid doing that from a VM perspective

Answer (score 1):

This can for sure be sped up a lot using numpy. You could define your function something like this:

```
def find_carry_numpy(x, y, c_out, bit):
    return 2 * c_out + bit - np.sum(x & y[::-1])
```

Create some random data:

```
In [36]: n = 100; c = 15; bit = 1

In [37]: x_arr = np.random.rand(n) > 0.5

In [38]: y_arr = np.random.rand(n) > 0.5

In [39]: x_list = list(x_arr)

In [40]: y_list = list(y_arr)
```

Check that results are the same:

```
In [42]: find_carry_numpy(x_arr, y_arr, c, bit)
Out[42]: 10

In [43]: findCarryIn(x_list, y_list, c, bit)
Out[43]: 10
```

Quick speed test:

```
In [44]: timeit find_carry_numpy(x_arr, y_arr, c, bit)
10000 loops, best of 3: 19.6 µs per loop

In [45]: timeit findCarryIn(x_list, y_list, c, bit)
1000 loops, best of 3: 409 µs per loop
```

So you gain a factor of 20 in speed! That is a pretty typical speedup when converting Python code to Numpy.

Comment: x and y are lists, I get an error TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'list' and 'list'

Comment: I assumed that `x` and `y` are numpy arrays. Give some time, trying to do some profiling now ...

Comment: I changed it to `np.dot(x, y[::-1])`, and the program failed with RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in long_scalars

Comment: @RenéG How big are your x and y? And do they contain normal ints?

Comment: Just 1s and 0s... I don't know what's going on. Anyway, the problem is x and y are actually stacks, all I do with them is append() and pop(). This is not very easy with numpy, I would have to manually track the stack pointer.

Comment: The thing is though, I know the maximum size of the stack, so there should be an easy way to do it without a performance hit.

Comment: just write some throw-away stack class: `class Stack(Object):def __init__(self, size): self.i = 0; self.stack = np.zeros(size); def push(self, val): self.stack[self.i] = val; self.i += 1; def pop(self): val = self.stack[self.i]; self.i -= 1; return val`.

Comment: Another problem is reversal: in python I can get a reverse iterator, which is an O(1) operation, but in numpy it actually reverses in place, which is an O(n) operation.

Comment: @RenéG Not true, reversing a Numpy array with `[::-1]` is a [basic slicing operation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing), which creates a view on the original array. This costs a fixed overhead, but this will not copy the underlaying data, so it is also `O(1)`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that... I'll change my code to numpy, then.